# pointers and char arrays( comparing)

Tags: c

I am trying to take out a given byte from a char array that has a pointer attached to it. see example below. (I have excluded headers etc.)

```
unsigned char compareByte(char *str, unsigned char byteNbr,
    unsigned char lengthOfStr, char char2compare)
{
  //I am stuck here, but this is what I tried to do
  if (byteNbr > lengthOfStr)
  {
    return (unsigned char) 0;
  }
  else
  {
    if (char2compare == *str + (byteNbr))
    {  //<- probably where it goes wrong
      return (unsigned char) 1;
    }
    else
    {
      return (unsigned char) 0;
    }
  }

}

int main()
{
  unsigned char result;
  char string[] = "abcdefg";
  unsigned char byte2Compare = 2; //want to take out 'b' from string
  result = compareByte(string, byte2Compare, strlen(string), 'b');
  if (result == 1)
  {
    printf("they match! \n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("they don´t match!");
  }
}
```

I always get that "they don´t match" when I run it, do anyone have any idea how to make it work as planned?

I am thankful for any inputs.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Unrelated note: `if(byteNbr>lengthOfStr)` should be `if(byteNbr>=lengthOfStr)`, except if it is ok to compare to the terminating zero.

Comment: `return byteNbr <= lengthOfStr && char2compare == str[byteNbr-1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if(char2compare==*str+(byteNbr)){
```

to

```
if(char2compare==*(str + byteNbr - 1)){
```

`*str+(byteNbr)` is equivalent to `a + 2` = `c`

Answer (score 2):

Change `if` statement to below,

`if( char2compare == *(str + byteNbr - 1) )`

`*(str + byteNbr - 1)` This implies, dereferencing (`str` at base address + `1` (`2` - `1`)), which means value at address location of `(str + 1)`. Here `1` mean `sizeof(char)` bytes of next location.

Note: Arrays indexes always start from `0`. So when you say you want to look for byte `2` you actually mean array indexed at `1`.